# How do I add a rel=me in the body of a Google Sites page?

Tags: google-classic-sites

Does Google Sites support `rel="me"` on links? I'm finding with straight HTML it strips it right out and replaces it with `rel="nofollow"`. The same thing occurs if I try `rel="nofollow me"`.

Is there any way to get the `rel` attribute to work with Google Sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Sites automatically adds `rel="nofollow"` to all external links. There is no way to override or remove this - [Google Support Post](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=7ae5ac72bff0eab4&hl=en).

Internal links (links to pages within your own site) are no affected by this - you can add `rel="me"` to internal links and it won't be stripped out / replaced.

Answer (score 2):

That **[Google Support post](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=7ae5ac72bff0eab4&hl=en)** was updated awhile back. You can avoid Google's automatic `rel="nofollow"` on external links **IFF** you have your own non-Google hosted domain, or maybe any URL, pointing to your Google Site **[according to this follow-up](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/sites/w3utUjoTHJg/QfzEncRWsJMJ)**:

> Google just updated Google Sites so if you have a mapped web address
>   pointing to your site, [e.g. http://www.example.com], then the
>   `rel="nofollow"` will not be included on any links on your site when
>   viewed at the mapped address, but will be included on links at the
>   sites.google.com address.

Other than that, the same nofollow remains in place for Google Sites. Google hasn't responded to any of the inquiries requesting it be changed.